# How to do Databinding with Mahapps.Metro WindowCommands and Caliburn Micro?

Tags: c#, data-binding, caliburn.micro, mahapps.metro

I want to bind against a list of IScreens in my ShellViewModel

```
    ...

    public ObservableCollection<IScreen> RightWindowCommands
    {
        get
        {
            return this.rightWindowCommands;
        }
        set
        {
            this.rightWindowCommands = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.RightWindowCommands);
        }
    }

    ...
```

and use the list of screens in a Mahapps.Metro Window as WindowCommands

```
<controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <controls:WindowCommands ItemsSource="{Binding RightWindowCommands}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding .}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>           
    </controls:WindowCommands>
</controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```

It seems it doesn't work this way (the IScreen is printed out as text instead of resolving the view) but it works if I put this into a ListBox instead of MetroWindow.WindowCommands inside the window itself. It seems that Caliburn.Micro does not search this visual tree.

Any suggestions how to force caliburn to parse this to?

**Update:**

Log:Debug: Neither XML 'id' nor 'name' specified - using generated object name [Shells.MyViewModel#3FB40AD]
Log:Info: Action Convention Not Applied: No actionable element for get_Session.
Log:Info: Action Convention Not Applied: No actionable element for get_Session.
Log:Info: Action Convention Not Applied: No actionable element for Handle.
...

But nothing about resolving a view that did not work or trying to resolve a view.

Comment: Have you tried `cal:Bind.Model` instead?

Comment: @Charleh Hmm, tried cal:Bind.Model="ShellViewModel" but this doesn't seem to be the right syntax...

Comment: You need to bind to the `Model` itself, in that snippet you are trying to bind the model to a string - should be `cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}"` - this binds each item in the `ObservableCollection<IScreen>` to the `ContentControl` using caliburn conventions

Comment: @Charleh already tried cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}" but the result is the same... the name of the viewmodel is displayed as text instead of resolving and replacing with view

Comment: Sounds like your viewmodel can't be resolved then - have you got an `ILog` implementation for the console? e.g. in your bootstrapper `LogManager.GetLog = (e) => return new DebugLogger()` where `DebugLogger` is a simple logger which writes to the console (implements `ILog`). This can help in figuring out binding issues, but it simply sounds like the `ViewModelLocator` isn't finding your view (usually it will put a `TextBlock` in place with the name of the view instead of the actual view if it can't find it)

Comment: @Charleh ...but it works inside the window. So it seems to me caliburn didn't even tried to resolve the view

Comment: ... added some log output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with a workaround (that even looks more decoupled) using a *ContentControl* instead with a separate ViewModel instead of using the *DataTemplate*. *DataTemplate* works when it is used within the ContentControl's Content:

```
<controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <controls:WindowCommands>
        <controls:MetroContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding MySeparateViewModel}" />
    </controls:WindowCommands>
</controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```

The `cal:View.Model` looks onto a property of my *ShellViewModel*.
Hope this helps if someone else has the same problem to solve.

Comment: For anyone else that might run into this: http://caliburn.codeplex.com/workitem/6671.  Apparently DataTemplate binding doesn't work in CM currently.